# Как лучше подключать стили css

Tags: css

Некоторые подключают стили при помощи

```
<link...,
```

а другие при помощи

```
@ import
```

как лучше и правильнее подключать их?

Comment: через `<link rel="stylesheet" href="путь до css файла">`

Comment: Ответь пожалуйста через ответ. Взаимный лайк!)

Comment: Чем раньше браузер получит ссылку на стиль, тем быстрее он его скачает. Чтобы получить ссылку из @import, браузеру придётся сперва скачать стиль в котором прописан этот импорт, а значит это немного дольше чем просто прочитать ссылку из html-кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нет других условий, то с точки зрения производительности и официальным рекомендациям, например yahoo (https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink) нужно использовать

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="путь до css файла">
```

для подключения стилей css. Надеюсь смог помочь!)